# Database engine efficiency when selecting a column subset on a big view?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I'm working with a SQL Server 2012 database and have defined some views. Let's say the view `full_report` has 20 columns, built from values from other 4 tables (a main table and joins on other tables).

If I choose to select 3 columns for this view, will the database engine still process the remaining columns for every row in the result (with its related overhead) or will it be smart enough to skip those calculations (e.g. joins)?

Thanks for the information.

Comment: It should not process columns it does not need.

Comment: But if you have joins in the view of course it is going to perform the joins. Why or how would it know that it doesn't need to perform the entire query?

Comment: It is complicated.  However, the number of columns being selected presumably has little influence on the overall query performance, especially when joins and aggregations are involved.